# Bold fraction line

Tags: math-mode, rules, fractions

I would like to use a "bold style" for the fraction line in a math formula. I've seen it in some PDFs, but I do not know the proper command.

Answer (score 4):

I simply solved my problem with a `\newcommand`:

```
\newcommand{\thickfrac}[2]{\genfrac{}{}{3pt}{}{#1}{#2}}
```

Comment: I seem to have already seen this one: http://www.guitex.org/home/en/forum/5-tex-e-latex/78702-linea-di-frazione-in-grassetto